# Unrecognizable options in TNS Service name for a new System DSN in ODBC administrator, after installing Oracle Client 11gR2

Tags: windows, odbc, oracle-11g

On 64-bit Windows 10 Enterprise, I was asked to install win32_11gR2_client.
But I encountered the following problems.

When I run setup.exe  in the top directory temporarily as an administrator, I got the following warning message:

> [INS-13001] Environment does not meet minimum requirements. Are you sure you want to continue?

It then created a log under the path of the administrator user, and I as a regular user don't know how to see it.

[image]

I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/49935363, but it didn't work:

> Right click on the setup.exe for the Oracle 11g 32-bit client, and
> select Properties. Select the Compatibility tab, and set the
> Compatibility mode to Windows 7. Click OK to close the Properties tab.
> Double click setup.exe to install the client.

Since it was a warning, I was still able to continue the installation, and I chose Instant Client to install.

After the installation, I ran ODBC Administrator as an administrator of the OS, and attempted to create a system DSN, where I selected Oracle in OraClient11g_home1 as the driver, but the dropdown list for TNS Service Name consists of unrecognizable names.

[image]

[image]

I was wondering how I could solve the problems (the second problem in particular).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Long shot but try doing the DSN stuff using the 64-bit OBDC control panel applet here instead of the 32-bit one, even though you are using 32-bit Oracle:

c:\windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe